# Keys stopped working on my laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> keys stopped working on my laptop. What could I do to try and fix this?

Edit: I have taken the keys off and cleaned under them and used a can of air on them. I am using Windows Vista and the laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A135-S4427.

Comment: please provide some more info: make and model of your laptop? operating system? and are you sure it's not just a case of Fn Lock or Num Lock?

Comment: This also just started happening with my Dell Inspiron 1720. But it seems intermittent... sometimes they work sometimes they don't. Weird.

Answer (score 10):

I just had this problem (why I found this thread) and I was able to fix it by pushing the c, e, and d button at the same time and hold them down for a few seconds.  I have no idea what caused it why this fixed but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: worked for me too.

Comment: Worked for me on a Lenovo T470s.

Comment: wow ! it worked for me as well on Rapoo keyboard!

Comment: Worked after a few times. Why is this?

Answer (score 8):

Keyboards are constructed as a grid of rows and columns.  Pressing a key connects a row to a column, which is how the key is identified.  When a whole row or column stops working (3,e,d,c is a column), and only a single row or column, it is usually not the individual keys.  It is more likely to be the internal wiring of the keyboard.

The row and column circuit traces often connect to ribbon cables that go to a separate little circuit board.  Those ribbon cables can develop a bad connection, the circuit trace for the column or row can get damaged or have a bad solder joint, or there can be a failure on that little circuit board.  If you have some technical skills, you might be able to identify the problem and repair it.  There are a number of online tutorials, such as [this one](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/fix-broken-keyboard-connector-on-laptop-motherboard/).

If the problem involves multiple keys that are not entire rows or columns (e.g., a whole column plus some other keys), the problem is often that something spilled on the keyboard.  There are many sources on how to try to repair that.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's just 6 years later, but I had that same problem 3 (+4) E D C didn't work. In my case, the problem was the connection to the motherboard.

I got my notebook cleaned and the problem with the keys started.

What I did was simply remove the keyboard, disconnect it from the motherboard, clean the cable and its slot. After I reconnected it, everything worked as before.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a hardware problem being in a line like that. Clean the keyboard with a can of compressed air, see if there's anything sticking under those keys. Be careful, you might shift whatever it is to somewhere worse or tricky to get to. If you want to, you might be able to remove the keyboard for better access. If it's a fairly popular laptop, a google of "laptop name remove keyboard" should find a tutorial or video.

Comment: I have a few computers :)

Comment: Definitely 'hardwareish'

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try cleaning it in case dirt got underneath the keyboard. If you have a compressed air can, spray it underneath the keys while holding the laptop so the keyboard faces downward. If you don't have a compressed air can, blow on it!

You can use [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) to ensure they are correctly mapped.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a common problem you can easily solve: Just remove your keyboard ribbon cable from the motherboard slot, and clean it. That will solve your problem.

I just did in my Acer Aspire V laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem. Luckily, the solution was simple. I popped out the offending keys using a delicately placed pencil. I then spotted a hair and removed it. Popped the keys back in and voila - good as new.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP has already cleaned under his keys.